# bash function scope and variable scope

Tags: bash

Here is a simplified set of bash commands that reproduce the problem I encounter in a script:

```
X=9
true && f() { (( x++ )) ; echo hello } ; f
```

which return

```
hello
```

then

```
echo $X
```

return

```
X=9
```

Where I was expecting to get X=10

Can you explain why the global variable is not modified within the function?

I know that global variables are not modified in subshell but this is not the case in this example.
The observed behaviour (variable scoping) seems to be related to the fact that the function is declared in a "conditional statement" : after &&.

Answer (score 5):

Capital global X and the function calls a lowercase x.  Those are 2 different variables.